# How can i use sed to replace a string with a variable string?

Tags: sed

I am trying the following command

```
new_line=My name is Eric Johnson
sed -i '/# My name is Eric/c\'"${new_line}" /tmp/foo"
```

Bash sees new_line above in the sed command as a file and says no such file. What is the right way to use the variable in the sed command to replace a whole line with a new line.

Comment: I think I found an answer to use double quotes so bash knows to expand the variables- sed -i "/# My name is Eric/c \\${new_line}" /tmp/foo.  Gonna try and update the answer.

Comment: It did work but not in this case - ssh {args} remote-host "sed -i "/# My name isEric/c \\${new_line}" /tmp/foo"  -  sed: -e expression #1, char 2: unterminated address regex.

Comment: I needed an extra single quotes around the text - sudo sed -i '/# My name is Eric/c \\${new_line}' /tmp/foo"

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, this is one of those corners of `sed` which is poorly standardized. Some variants will absolutely require the newline to be escaped with a backslash; others will regard the escaped newline as something which should be removed before processing.

As a general rule of thumb, use single quotes around your `sed` scripts in order to prevent the shell from also modifying the arguments even before `sed` starts.  *However,* that means the value of `$new_line` will not be interpolated.  A common workaround is what I call "seesaw quoting"; put the majority of the script in single quotes, but switch to double quotes where you need the shell to interpolate a variable.

```
sed -i 's/# My name is Eric Johnson/c\'"${new_line}/" file
```

Notice how `"foo"'bar' = "foobar" = 'foobar' = foobar` (even the unquoted token is okay as long as the string doesn't contain any shell metacharacters, though this is usually not recommended practice).

As a further aside,

```
new_line=My name is Eric Johnson
```

is not correct for this case; it will assign `new_line=My` and then run the command line `name is Eric Johnson` with this variable assignment in place.  When the command finishes (or, as on my computer, the shell reports `name: command not found` the value of `new_line` is reverted to its previous state (undefined if it wasn't defined, or back to its previous value).

Comment: edit - That should have been new_line="My name is Eric Johnson". I apologize.